# How Can I Check a Number is a Certain Length in Cerberus?

Tags: validation, schema, cerberus

I'm writing a book schema with Cerberus but I've stumbled upon a block. I want the ISBN field to accept a number/integer/digit that is either 10 digits long, or 13. How can I go about that? I tried using `maxlength` and `minlength` but they don't seem to work.

Comment: Cerberus doesn't use JSON Schema, so any assumptions you've made that it uses JSON Schema are wrong. https://github.com/pyeve/cerberus/issues/254

Answer (score 2):

Since you're dealing with integers, the rules `min` and `max` can be used to define constraints on a field's [minimum or maximum value](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#min-max).

As always, you're very likely to get a helpful answer when you provided some code examples of what you've achieved so far.